# Finding a function with desirable behaviour

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions

I was playing around with math in my spare time and came up with the following problem. Suppose I have a $1$-parameter family of lines in the plane. Each line is given by the following equation
\begin{equation}
l_t:\alpha(t) x+\beta(t)y+\gamma(t)=0
\end{equation}
where $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are given well-behaved functions ($C^\infty$ if you want). I would like to define a function $\mu:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ which could capture the idea of *"line density at a point"*.

*Example $1$.* Suppose the family is given by
\begin{equation}
l_t:\cos(t)x+\sin(t)y=0
\end{equation}
These lines are all passing through the origin; if we consider $t$ as a uniform random variable on $[0,2\pi]$, the lines are in a sense "more dense" at the origin than farther away. I expect the function $\mu$ to have a radial symmetry and to be decreasing with the distance from the origin: the lines are getting more and more "sparse".

*Example $2$.* Suppose the family is given by
\begin{equation}
l_t:y-t=0
\end{equation}
These are all lines parallel to the $x$-axis. In this case I would like the function $\mu$ to be constant, as an uniform distribution of $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$ translates in an "uniform distribution" of the lines in the plane.

The question is: does such a function exist in literature? A physical (but discrete) image of the problem would be this: given some laser beam disposition on a plane, set $\mu$ to be  the light intensity at any given point.

I don't know what kind of answer to expect; any insight on the problem will be appreciated (i.e. considered as an acceptable answer).

Comment: I'm writing ony a comment, since this is not based on literature as you requested. You essentially have some function $f(x,y,t)$ which defines $l_t: f(x,y,t)=0$. If you fix a point $P=(x,y)$ in the plane, then $g_P(t)=f(x,y,t)$ is a function in one parameter. The question “how many lines pass *exactly* through $P$?” translates to “how many roots does $g_P$ have?“ But for density, you might be equally interested in the question “How does a slight change of $P$ affect $t$”, i.e. how do the roots change if you modify the parameters. It might be worthwhile to focus on rational functions first.